# Java hashtables - Optimizing existing code

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, data-structures, hashtable

I have implented a hashtale in java but I need to optimize the code. I think that I have to many loops. How can I "cut down" the number of loops ? The problem is that when I remove a element then i have to rehash the table and then I have mane hops beetwen delete() and put(). I don't want any code examples, just guidance because this is a school excersise :)

Thank you

Here is my functions:

```
public void put(String key, Character val) {
    int hashValue = hash(key); 

    if(val == '\r'){
        delete(key); 
    }
    else {
    while(keys[hashValue] != null) {
        if(keys[hashValue].equals(key)) {
            break; 
        }
        hashValue = (hashValue + 1) % M ;  

    }

    keys[hashValue] = key ; 
    vals[hashValue] = val; 
    N++; 
  }
} 

public Character get(String key) {

    int hashValue = hash(key); 
    while(keys[hashValue] != null) {
        if(keys[hashValue].equals(key)){
            return vals[hashValue]; 
        }
        hashValue = (hashValue+1) % M; 
    }
    return null; 
} 

public void delete(String key) {

     int hashValue = hash(key) ; 

     String tempkey; 
     Character tempval; 
     boolean deleted = false; 

     while(keys[hashValue] != null){
         if(keys[hashValue].equals(key)){
             keys[hashValue] = null; 
             vals[hashValue] = null;
             deleted = true;  
             N--; 
             if(keys[(hashValue + 1) % M] == null){ 
                 break; 
             }
         }
         else if(deleted = true){
             tempkey = keys[hashValue]; 
             tempval = vals[hashValue]; 

             keys[hashValue] = null; 
             vals[hashValue] = null; 
             N--; 
             put(tempkey, tempval); 
         }

         hashValue = (hashValue +1) % M; 

     }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement should also be `deleted == true`, with 2 `=`s.

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung. What do you mean ?

Comment: @Eric, yes of course, how could I miss that :) Clumsy me :)

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung, yes you are right, I will fix it :)

Comment: I have found a solution :) The problem was that I had delete = true instead of delete == true :D

Comment: @user1285737 Check your IDE - many will supply warnings for this, might be worth turning this on / changing IDE.

Comment: Parallel arrays (`keys[]` and `vals[]`) were appropriate in Fortran77 and Dartmouth BASIC.  You should use real data structures in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say you need to rethink the design of what you are trying to do. Specifically collisions. It looks like you are trying to resolve collisions (two values that have the same hashcode) by moving the value into the next bucket. When you repeatedly add and delete, there is no way to be sure your key isn't somewhere else in the table.

You might want to design your hashtable as a table of linked lists. That way the colliding entries are put in a linked list that starts at the correct cell. If you use a proper hashing function (one that distributes the keys close to uniform over keyspace) the number of collisions will be minimal.

Good luck!